# ¿Cómo sacar la letra que más veces aparece en una cadena con Java?

Tags: java

llevo varios días atascada con este ejercicio lo único que he podido resolver es que me muestre cuantas vocales tiene la cadena de texto que se ha introducido por Scanner. He conseguido que me muestre cuantas veces se repiten las letras, pero lo que no logro hacer es que me muestre únicmente la letra con mayor número de repeticiones y el número de veces que se repite.

```
public class Supuesto3 {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        //Creación de Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Pedimos la cadena por teclado
        String cadena;
        System.out.println("Introduce una frase: ");
        cadena = input.nextLine();

        int contadorVocales = 0;
        char letraArray [] = cadena.toCharArray();
        char letra;
        int contadorLetraRepetida = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<cadena.length(); i++){
            switch(cadena.charAt(i)){
                case 'a':case 'e':case 'i':case 'o':case 'u':
                    contadorVocales++;
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Hay " + contadorVocales + " vocales.");

        for(int j =0;j<letraArray.length;j++){
            letra = letraArray[j];

            for(int k=0;k<letraArray.length;k++){
                if(letraArray[k]==letra){
                    contadorLetraRepetida++;
                }
            }
        System.out.println("La letra " + letraArray[j] + " se repite "+ contadorLetraRepetida + " veces.");
        contadorLetraRepetida= 0;
        }   
    }
}
```

Salida:

[image: Salida]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas 2 variables, una para guardar la letra que se repite más y otra para llevar la cuenta de repeticiones máxima encontrada. Podrías usar para ello la variable `letra` para guardar la letra más repetida que vayas encontrando y `contadorLetraRepetida` para guardar el número de repeticiones máximo que vayas obteniendo. En otro contador puedes llevar la cuenta temporal y si éste supera a `contadorLetraRepetida` entonces actualizas las variables anteriores con la letra actual y el número de veces encontrada:

```
public class Supuesto3 {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        //Creación de Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Pedimos la cadena por teclado
        String cadena;
        System.out.println("Introduce una frase: ");
        cadena = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();//Pasa la cadena a minúsculas

        int contadorVocales = 0;
        char letraArray[] = cadena.toCharArray();
        char letra = letraArray[0];
        int contadorLetraRepetida = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<cadena.length(); i++){
            switch(cadena.charAt(i)){
                case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
                    contadorVocales++;
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Hay " + contadorVocales + " vocales.");

        for(int j =0;j<letraArray.length;j++){
            int contador = 0;//Antes de recorrer el array pongo el contador en 0
            for(int k=0;k<letraArray.length;k++){
                if(letraArray[j] == letraArray[k]) //Letra encontrada
                    contador++;
            }
            if(contadorLetraRepetida < contador) { //Si la letra actual superó a la que había antes
                contadorLetraRepetida = contador; //Actualiza el contador de repeticiones con el número máximo
                letra = letraArray[j]; //Actualiza la letra
            }
        }

        System.out.println("La letra '" + letra + "' se repite "+ contadorLetraRepetida + " veces.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Utilizando `Collections` podrías obtener el mismo resultado en menos código:

- Primero debemos de importar todas las librerías que usaremos:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;// Arrays , nos ayuda a transformar un split() a List
import java.util.Collections;// Nos permitirá sacar la cantidad que una letra aparece
import java.util.List;//Necesitaremos una lista para pasar como parámetro
import java.util.Scanner; // Para tomar la entrada por consola
```

El código de lo que quieres hacer quedaría más o menos como:

```java
public class Contando {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in  = new Scanner(System.in);
        String textoEntrada;
        //para el asunto de las vocales
        String[] vocales = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"};
        int cantVocales = 0;
        //Tomamos el texto desde la consola
        System.out.println("Introduce un texto de entrada");
        textoEntrada = in.nextLine();

        String letraMasRepetida = "";
        int cantidadRepetida = 0;

        //Transformamos la frase a una lista, 
        //así podremos buscar las letras duplicadas con Collections
        List<String> textoList = Arrays.asList(textoEntrada.split(""));

        //contamos las vocales
        for (String v : vocales){
            cantVocales += Collections.frequency(textoList, v);
        }        
        System.out.println("Hay " + cantVocales + " vocales");
        
        //Recorremos y contamos todo
        for(String item : textoList){
            //pasamos como primer parámetro la lista
            // y como segundo la letra que queremos contar
            int cantidad = Collections.frequency(textoList, item);
            // con esto comprobamos que no sea un espacio en blanco
            if(cantidadRepetida < cantidad && !item.equals(" ")){
                letraMasRepetida = item;
                cantidadRepetida = cantidad;
            }
            System.out.println("La letra " + item + " se repite  " + cantidad);
        }
        //imprimimos la letra que más se repite
        System.out.println(String.format("La letra %s es la que mayor se repite, con %o veces", letraMasRepetida, cantidadRepetida));
    }
    
}
```

Para contar las vocales, tenemos un ciclo `for` que recorre un `Array` de `String` que contiene las vocales, utilizando `Collections`, vemos cuantas vocales hay en total

Esta línea:

```java
List<String> textoList = Arrays.asList(textoEntrada.split(""));
```

Hacemos un `split()` al texto de entrada y con ayuda de `Arrays` lo transformamos a `List`,  el resultado lo almacena la variable `textoList` que es de tipo `List`.

Después de esto, solo hacemos un ciclo `for` el cual recorre la lista y contamos los datos con `Collections` y su método `frequency()`

### SALIDA:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Más información de Collections en español](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2015/09/25/introduccion-a-colecciones-en-java/)

Answer (score 1):

Esta es otra opción

```
String input = "Hola tengo una duda";
// Eliminamos los espacios en blanco
input = input.replace(" ", "");
// Convertimos todo a mayusculas o minusculas
input = input.toUpperCase();
// Obenemos el arreglo de caracteres de la cadena limpia
char letras[] = input.toCharArray();

// Mapa para contar cada letra
Map<Character, Integer> countMap = new HashMap();
for (char letra : letras) {
    try {
        countMap.put(letra, countMap.get(letra) + 1);
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        // Entramos aquí la primera vez que se encuentra una nueva letra
        countMap.put(letra, 1);
    }
}
char letraModa = Collections.max(countMap.entrySet(), Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)).getKey();
System.out.println("La letra de moda en el texto ingresado es: " + letraModa + ", con una frecuencia de: " + countMap.get(letraModa));

countMap.keySet().forEach((letra) -> {
    System.out.println("Letra [" + letra + "]: " + countMap.get(letra));
});
```

Comment: Esta solución es interesante por el HashMap, sin embargo, la pregunta se enfoca en encontrar la letra que más se repite. Tu código hace lo contrario (busca la vocal que más se repite).

Comment: @MrDave1999 Disculpa, tienes razón ahora mismo lo modifico